# integral of differences of vector

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a vector function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined with components
$$
f_i(a) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(a_i - a_j)
$$
which I want to integrate from ${\bf{\alpha}}^0$ to ${\bf{\alpha}}^1$ where ${\bf{\alpha}}^k = [\alpha^k_1, \ldots, \alpha^k_n]$ for $k \in \{1,2\}$.
So the problem looks like
$$
\int_{{\bf{\alpha}}^0}^{{\bf{\alpha}}^1} f(a)^{\top} {\rm d}\, a.
$$
I thought that I could integrate as below
$$
\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(a_i - a_j)\right\} {\rm d}a_i 
$$
by expanding the inner product in the integrand. I think that I can then write the integral as
$$
\int_{(\alpha_1^0, \ldots, \alpha_n^0)}^{(\alpha_1^1, \ldots, \alpha_n^1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(a_i - a_j)\right\} {\rm d}a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\hat{\alpha}_i^0}^{\hat{\alpha}_i^1} \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(a_i - a_j)\right\} {\rm d}a_i
$$
where $\hat{\alpha}_i^0$ treats every component of $a$ as fixed $\alpha_j^0$ for $j \neq i$, which I think would give
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left[ \cos(\alpha_i^1 - \alpha_j^1) - \cos(\alpha_i^0 - \alpha_j^0) \right].
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The problem here is in the original expression, which is not well-defined. You have $a_i$ as the dummy variable for a definite integral (in which case it should disappear), but then you're expecting to be able to sum over $i$ after everything else is done. I think if you provide more context, we might be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, thank you, i added the full problem

Comment: @AdrianKeister, i guess there is a third summation over $k$ because of the inner product?

Comment: It's really depending on the correct interpretation of the original integral. If it's a dot product, then each differential is multiplying one component of $f$ that itself depends on all the $a_i$ - that's problematic. I don't see how you're going to get a single number out of that unless it's a line integral. If it's a line integral, then parametrization is the way to go, assuming we have a well-defined one we can use. Otherwise, if the integral is really more of a volume integral, then every component of $f$ gets multiplied by all the differentials: you can get a single number out of that.

Comment: All right! I think I've got it. Please check over my answer for errors.

Comment: Gorgeous problem, by the way! Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are asked to compute the line integral 
$$\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1}f(a)\cdot da, $$
where
$$f_i(a)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin(a_i-a_j).$$
Ideally, this line integral is path-independent. We would need $f=\nabla g$ for some scalar field $g(a).$ That is, we would need
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin(a_i-a_j)=\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\,g(a).$$
This would force
$$\int\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin(a_i-a_j)\,da_i=g(a),$$
or
$$g(a)=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\cos(a_i-a_j).$$
But this needs to be true of all the $a_i,$ so let's modify this to
$$g(a)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(a_i-a_j).$$
When $i=j,$ we're going to pick up a number of $-1$'s, but that should be immaterial. The point is, that if we differentiate this $g(a)$ w.r.t. $a_i,$ we'll get $f_i.$ Let's double-check that this works by computing:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a_1}&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(a_i-a_j)\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_j).
\end{align*}
Now we see here that if neither $i$ nor $j$ is $1,$ the derivative annihilates the $\cos$. So, which terms have $a_1$ in them? Well, we have a number of terms. If $i=1,$ and $j\not=1,$ those will contribute. Also, if $i\not=1$ but $j=1,$ those will also contribute. If $i=j,$ then, as before mentioned, the term is $\cos(0)=1,$ which disappears under differentiation. Therefore, the expression above becomes the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a_1}&=
-\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_1-a_j)-\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_1).
\end{align*}
Since $\cos$ is even, these sums will actually turn out to be identical, which means we double-counted initially. That is:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a_1}&=
-\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_j-a_1)-\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_1) \\
&=-\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_1)-\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_1) \\
&=-2\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\,\cos(a_i-a_1) \\
&=2\sum_{i=2}^n\sin(a_i-a_1).
\end{align*}
This means we need to adjust our $g$ by a factor of $1/2:$
$$g(a)=-\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(a_i-a_j).$$
Once we do this, we can see that the proof above goes through, and it is indeed the case that $\partial_{a_1}g(a)=f_1,$ since in $f_1,$ when $j=1,$ we see that $\sin(a_1-a_1)=\sin(0)=0.$

Whew! We have path independence on account of the form of $f$. It remains to calculate the line integral itself, but we've actually done all the hard work because we know what $g$ is. Since the integral is path-independent, we'll choose the straight line from $\alpha^0$ to $\alpha^1,$ parametrized as 
$$\gamma(t)=t\alpha^1+(1-t)\alpha^0,\quad t\in[0,1],$$
as it has all the nice properties we need to use the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1}f(a)\cdot da &=\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1}(\nabla g(a))\cdot da \\
&=g(\alpha^1)-g(\alpha^0) \\
&=\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(\alpha_i^0-\alpha_j^0)-\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(\alpha_i^1-\alpha_j^1) \\
&=\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[\cos(\alpha_i^0-\alpha_j^0)-\cos(\alpha_i^1-\alpha_j^1)].
\end{align*}
You could use
$$\cos(\theta)-\cos(\varphi)=-2\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\varphi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\varphi}{2}\right)$$
to combine the cosines in the last expression, but that might or might not be simpler.

Comment: i think this is close, but then what is $\alpha_j$?

Comment: Oh, yeah, we've got a problem, here. The $i$ and $j$ range over the same limit, and I think there might be a problem with the differential.

Comment: You might need to define the differential as $\prod_k da_k$. Then you might have to take different cases. If $i=j,$ then the sum doesn't contribute. So you know in advance that $i\not=j$. Take the cases $k=i, k=j,$ and $k$ not equal to either.

Comment: ok wait, SORRY, i think i messed up $f$...

Comment: what if it the $i$-th component is just a sum over $j$

Comment: So, you trying to compute $\int f$ or $\int f_i?$

Comment: $\int f(a) \cdot da$ for $a$ a vector

Comment: So that's going to look like $\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\alpha_j^0}^{\alpha_j^1}\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(a_i-a_j)\,da_i,$ I think, which is what you had above.

Comment: Ah yes (interchanging cos for sin). So this is not well defined?

Comment: Oh, right - definitely sin. I think it's ok, because fundamentally it's a sum of integrals (that's the dot product). I don't think my answer is correct. The final result should be a number involving only $\alpha_i^0$ and $\alpha_i^1$.

Comment: It's going to be $\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\alpha_i^0}^{\alpha_i^1}\sum_{j=1}^n\sin(a_i-a_j)\,da_i,$ right?

Comment: So I think it boils down to that, but i guess i'm not sure how to break up the integral over vector values (as in the re-edited question). If $\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1}$ can be split into components, then yep thats what it should be (since we can swap sum / int)

Comment: i added a new approach basically subsituting in $\alpha$ for the $a_j$s... Do you think this works?

Comment: It just hit me: I think this is a line integral, right? Going back to the original expression you're asked to evaluate: $\displaystyle\int_{\alpha^0}^{\alpha^1}f(a)\cdot da.$ Aren't $\alpha^0$ and $\alpha^1$ vectors of the same dimension as $f$ and $a?$ If it's a line integral, then we need to know what path (if it matters) you mean to take from the starting point to the finishing point. Then we should parameterize the expression and compute like this: $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(a(t))\cdot \dot{a}(t)\,dt.$

Comment: ah yeah youre right, it is a line integral. But somehow i think it is supposed to be path-independent?

Comment: It could well be path-independent - that would certainly simplify our lives a bit. Let me check on that... We'll need $f$ to be the gradient of a scalar field.

Comment: Or do you happen to have a path picked out for you?

Comment: this is so clear, thank you so much!!

Comment: You're very welcome!